# sqlite select minimum function value of grouped result

Tags: sql, function, sqlite, group-by, min

I have a table with gps locations of restaurants chains and would like to return the addresses of the restaurants closest to point (A) within a certain radius

```
SELECT *
    , MIN(distance($lat, $lon, lat, lon)) as miles 
FROM all_restaurants 
WHERE lat between $lat1 and $lat2 
    AND lon between $lon1 and $lon2 
    AND miles < $miles 
GROUP BY restaurant_id 
ORDER BY miles ASC
    , company_name ASC 
LIMIT 500
```

returns error

> misuse of aggregate: MIN()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lamak was somewhat right but this is what i ended up doing instead

```
SELECT *, distance('+lat+','+lon+', lat, lon) as minmiles
FROM all_restaurants 
WHERE restaurant_id || minmiles IN 
( 
    SELECT restaurant_id || MIN(miles) as fewmiles 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT restaurant_id, distance('+lat+','+lon+', lat, lon) as miles 
        FROM restaurant_master_combined 
        WHERE lat BETWEEN $lat AND $lat2 AND lon BETWEEN $lon1 AND $lon2 AND miles < $miles
    ) 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id 
)
ORDER BY ROUND(minmiles) ASC, company_name ASC
```

hope this helps somebody else

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you only are grouping by `restaurant_id`. When you use an aggregation function as `MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG`, etc, you need to include every column in the `SELECT` statement that are not in any aggregation function. In this case you have two options, either in the `SELECT` you only put `restaurant_id` as the following:

```
SELECT restaurant_id 
        , MIN(distance($lat, $lon, lat, lon)) as miles 
    FROM all_restaurants 
    WHERE lat between $lat1 and $lat2 
        AND lon between $lon1 and $lon2 
        AND miles < $miles 
    GROUP BY restaurant_id 
    ORDER BY miles ASC
        , company_name ASC 
    LIMIT 500
```

Or you put every other column included in the '*' on the grouping (because you can't use `GROUP BY *`).

Answer (score 0):

I bet that you're calling a function which is `distance($lat, $lon, lat, lon)`, don't you?

Have you tried using a simple subtraction between `$lat` and `lat` and have it return the minimum value using the `MIN` function?

`MIN`'s purpose is for use with a table field or some basic operation such as a subtraction, I guess. This might be the cause of the encountered error.

Up and foremost, avoid using `*` while using aggregation functions, list the columns you require in your query.

Perhaps providing us with sample data might help us find a way around to work you through.